# How to split a decimal number from a string in R

Tags: r

For example:

```
c("2.11abc","15.1cde",".562342rfg")
```

How to split the numeric out of this vector? 
The vector I would like to have is

```
c(2.11, 15.1, 0.562342)
```

I tried

```
gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", a)
```

but the result was

```
c(211, 151 ,562342)
```

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7):

If have more troublesome strings, in which periods can appear outside of the number part of the string, you might want to use something like this.

```
library(gsubfn)

## A possibly more realistic character vector
x <- c("2.11abc.def","a.b-15.1cde",".562342rfg", "abcdef")

getNumberPart <- function(x) {
    pat <- "(-?(\\d*\\.*\\d+|\\d+\\.))"
    strapply(x, pattern=pat, FUN=as.numeric, simplify=TRUE, empty=NA)
}

getNumberPart(x)
# [1]  2.110000 -15.100000   0.562342         NA
```

Do note that if a string contains more than one number, `strapply()` will extract all of them, and will return the overall result as a list (rather than a simple vector) with one list element per input string.

Comment: Or via base: `regmatches(x,regexpr("(^|\\d+)\\.\\d+",x))` or similar.

Comment: @thelatemail -- Yeah, and in fact that's what I typically use. The problem is that here, that'll silently drop strings with *no* digits in them, which could be quite troublesome. `strapply()`'s `empty=` argument solves this issue a lot more succinctly than I could with `regmatches(regexpr())`.

Comment: That is a bit of a nuisance admittedly.

Comment: I had already voted on this last night, but I think you'll need some slight modification if there are any negative numbers.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed it to handle negative numbers as well.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the period:

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:].]", "", c("2.11abc","15.1cde",".562342rfg")))
# [1]  2.110000 15.100000  0.562342
```

Comment: Though be careful if a period might occur anywhere other than within the number part of the string (as in `"2.11abc.def"` or `"a.b215"`, for example)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thank you for pointing out that. I found the first scenario (    "2.11abc.def") did exist in my data. Have to finger out another way. :(

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity of use, I would suggest looking at the "qdapRegex" package, with which you can do:

```
x <- c("2.11abc.def","a.b15.1cde","-.562342rfg", "abcdef")

library(qdapRegex)
rm_number(x, extract = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "2.11"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "15.1"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "-.562342"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] NA
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
a <- c("2.11abc","15.1cde",".562342rfg")
substr(a, 1, regexpr("[a-zA-Z]", a)-1)
```