# What is the best way to tidy data and extract numbers (double) from data frame in R?

Tags: r, parsing, tidyverse

I have a data frame that contains survey responses.  What is the best way to extract the numbers and change them to a double type variable?

Here is a little sample:

```
a <- ("10.5", "about 30", "25 per month")
tibble(a)
```

I have tried

```
parse_double(a)
```

and it seems like I am close. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting decimal numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252663/extracting-decimal-numbers-from-a-string)

Comment: Also 4 more options [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28819761/5325862) and another 11 options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14543627/5325862) that just need to be amended to include the decimal point

Answer (score 1):

We need `parse_number`

```
library(readr)
parse_number(a)
[1] 10.5 30.0 25.0
```

---

The difference is that `parse_double` works on character vectors with only digits + `.` as the characters whereas `parse_number` extracts the numeric part from a string which also include non-numeric characters

#### data

```
a <- c("10.5", "about 30", "25 per month")
```

Comment: My solution is faster ;)))

Comment: Did you have any tasks in your practice, where were some requirements to the execution time?

Comment: If we want to achieve a time efficency of the code - we must use basic functions of R?

Answer (score 1):

I know a solution too (from `base` package)

```
a <- c("10.5", "about 30", "25 per month")
as.numeric(gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", a)) 


 > as.numeric(gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", a))
 [1] 10.5 30.0 25.0
 > end_time <- Sys.time()
 > end_time - start_time
 Time difference of 0.01400113 secs
 > start_time <- Sys.time()
 > parse_number(a)
 [1] 10.5 30.0 25.0
 > end_time <- Sys.time()
 > end_time - start_time
 Time difference of 0.1500092 secs
```

My solution is faster than [that provided by Akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69589565).